# Why doesn't preventDefault() stop redirect on this form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've been trying to submit this form with jQuery but I can't seem to stop it from redirecting after I submit it. Where am I going wrong?

My form simplified:

```
<form action="http://xxxxxxx" method="post" id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="my_field">
  <a class="last">Submit<a>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('.last').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#myform').valid()) {
    $('#myform').submit();
  }

  $('#myform').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.getJSON(
      this.action + "?callback=?",
      $(this).serialize(),
      function(data) {
        if (data.Status === 400) {
          alert(data.Message);
          $('#noti').text(error).addClass('notice-error', function() {
            $('.last').attr('id', '#contact-us-btn').addClass('button-error').html('Contact us');
          });
          $('#contact-us-btn').on('click', function() {
            zE(function() {
              zE.show();
            });
          });
        } else {
          console.log(data.Message);
          $('#step-3').slideUp(function() {
            $('#noti').text(success).addClass('text-success');
            $('.next, .previous').fadeOut();
            $('.panel.success').slideDown();
          });
        }
      }
    )
  });
});
```

Comment: Thing is though, I have another form with the same structure that doesn't re-direct.. that's the most confusing part about it.

Comment: @MaxZoom: I don't think that's true. In this case, the user is submitting the form before the submit handler is assigned.

Comment: So, swap them around in order?

Comment: Ashley: You should bind the submit handler before you try to call `.submit()`. Also, you don't want to run this code every time the click event handler is called. You can line up your form submit event binding outside of the click handler, then do the validation check and submit triggering in the click handler.

Comment: @MaxZoom according to jquery docs event.preventDefault and return false would prevent the form submission; the issue is that the submit event is being asigned inside the click event.

Comment: `return false` stops propagation and prevents the default submit behavior. If that's ok, `return false` is an option, but is a little more intrusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the order, the issue is that the second event was being assign inside the first event function (basically it would be assigned after the click therefore the form submission).

```
$('.last').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#myform').valid()) {
    $('#myform').submit();
  }
});

$('#myform').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.getJSON(
    this.action + "?callback=?",
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(data) {
      if (data.Status === 400) {
        alert(data.Message);
        $('#noti').text(error).addClass('notice-error', function() {
          $('.last').attr('id', '#contact-us-btn').addClass('button-error').html('Contact us');
        });
        $('#contact-us-btn').on('click', function() {
          zE(function() {
            zE.show();
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log(data.Message);
        $('#step-3').slideUp(function() {
          $('#noti').text(success).addClass('text-success');
          $('.next, .previous').fadeOut();
          $('.panel.success').slideDown();
        });
      }
    }
  )
});
```

Comment: Argh, rookie mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just have things occurring a little out of order. Currently you're triggering the default submit behavior before you're binding the custom handler. So, bind the handler first, *then* initiate the submit:

```
  $('#myform').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.getJSON(
      this.action + "?callback=?",
      $(this).serialize(),
      function(data) {
        if (data.Status === 400) {
          alert(data.Message);
          $('#noti').text(error).addClass('notice-error', function() {
            $('.last').attr('id', '#contact-us-btn').addClass('button-error').html('Contact us');
          });
          $('#contact-us-btn').on('click', function() {
            zE(function() {
              zE.show();
            });
          });
        } else {
          console.log(data.Message);
          $('#step-3').slideUp(function() {
            $('#noti').text(success).addClass('text-success');
            $('.next, .previous').fadeOut();
            $('.panel.success').slideDown();
          });
        }
      }
    )
  });

$('.last').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#myform').valid()) {
    $('#myform').submit();
  }
});
```